# 2d numpy mask not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to turn a 2x3 numpy array into a 2x2 array by removing select indexes.

I think I can do this with a mask array with true/false values.

Given

```
 [ 1,  2,  3],
 [ 4,  1,  6]
```

I want to remove one element from each row to give me:

```
 [ 2,  3],
 [ 4,  6]
```

However this method isn't working quite like I would expect:

```
import numpy as np

in_array = np.array([
 [ 1,  2,  3],
 [ 4,  1,  6]
])

mask = np.array([
 [False,  True,  True],
 [True,   False, True]
])

print in_array[mask]
```

Gives me:

```
[2 3 4 6]
```

Which is not what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing 'wrong' with that is it is the shape - 1d rather than 2.  But what if your mask was

```
mask = np.array([
 [False,  True,  False],
 [True,   False, True]
])
```

1 value in the first row, 2 in second.  It couldn't return that as a 2d array, could it?

So the default behavior when masking like this is to return a 1d, or raveled result.

Boolean indexing like this is effectively a `where` indexing:

```
In [19]: np.where(mask)
Out[19]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
In [20]: in_array[_]
Out[20]: array([2, 3, 4, 6])
```

It finds the elements of the mask which are true, and then selects the corresponding elements of the `in_array`.

Maybe the transpose of `where` is easier to visualize:

```
In [21]: np.argwhere(mask)
Out[21]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

and indexing iteratively:

```
In [23]: for ij in np.argwhere(mask):
    ...:     print(in_array[tuple(ij)])
    ...:     
2
3
4
6
```

Comment: In my case i'm guaranteed to only have one false per row.

Comment: I'm trying to remove a "seam" from a matrix and return the matrix with one fewer rows. I have all of the values I want to remove masked, I just don't know how to generate a new matrix without iterating which seems expensive.

Comment: Can't you just do this boolean indexing followed by reshape?