# Fastest numpy way to remove a list of cells from a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large 2D numpy array of m x n elements. For each row, I need to remove *exactly one element*. So for example from a 4x6 matrix I might need to delete [0, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3], and [3, 3] - I have this set of coordinates stored in a list. In the end, the matrix will ultimately shrink in width by 1.

Is there a standard way to do this using a mask? Ideally, I need this to be as performant as possible.

Comment: This current question is asking the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874102/2d-numpy-mask-not-working-as-expected.  Are you starting with the list of points or a boolean mask?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that use `ravel_multi_index()` to calculate one-dim index, and then `delete()` the elements, and `reshape` back to two-dim array:

```
import numpy as np

n = 12
a = np.repeat(np.arange(10)[None, :], n, axis=0)
index = np.random.randint(0, 10, n)
ravel_index = np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(n), index), a.shape)
np.delete(a, ravel_index).reshape(n, -1)
```

the index:

```
array([4, 6, 9, 0, 3, 5, 3, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4])
```

the result:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
       [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: How would you do it if you wanted to remove 1 element from each column rather than 1 element from each row?

Comment: @RanEldan You could just transpose the matrix.